# Simplify a vertex in the on-shell form

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory

I am calculating with a vertex connecting a pion, delta and a nucleon. In general, the vertex is calculated as

$$ \Gamma_{\pi N \Delta, a}^{\mu}  \sim \gamma^{\mu\nu\rho} (p_\pi)_{\nu}(p_\Delta)_\rho T_a, $$

with $p_\pi, p_\Delta$ the pion and delta momenta and $T_a$ are isospin 1/2 to 3/2 transition matrices. In the notes I have, the on-shell case leads to this simplification:

$$ \Gamma_{\pi N \Delta, a}^{\mu}  \sim  m_\Delta (p_\pi)^{\mu} T_a.$$

What on-shell case is meant here? Is it the case where the delta is on-shell and we use $p_\Delta^2=m_\Delta^2$ for the simplification or is it another particle on-shell in the simplification?

Comment: The indices on your vertex do not seem to match up, on the left you have one free index $\mu$, and on the right you have two free indices $\mu\rho$ as well as a triply repeated index $\nu$ and a free index $a$.

Comment: Yeah, I corrected $\nu$ to $\rho$. $a$ is just a three-index, in the notes I have it from, it is not on the left side, but I now edited it as well.

Comment: I think the Dirac equation is used, but I may be wrong

Comment: As schris pointed out, on-shellness for $\Delta$ particle may suggest $\not\!p_{\Delta}=m_\Delta$. You should recheck the definition of $\gamma^{\mu\nu\rho}$. Also, if your source were online source, I recommend you to put the url in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the momentum space equations of motion for the spin 3/2 field, schematically

$(\gamma^{\mu\nu\rho}p_{\rho} - m_{\Delta})\psi_{\nu} = 0$

which allows you to substitute in the mass for your slashed momentum in your equation.

Comment: So this means that we set $\gamma^\rho ({p} _\Delta)_\rho =m_\Delta$ and we get the result I stated earlier when the $\Delta$ is on-shell? For a on-shell pion we then could do the same for the pion momentum.